# Does the following region have positive area?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Does the following region have positive area?

$\{(x,y); x>0\}$.

Now we know the area is infinite. But is it wrong if I were to say that it does have positive area?

Comment: What's the range of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I don't think anyone should complain, if you say that it has. In the context of measure theory  (=an abstraction of concepts such as area of plane figures, volume of objects,...) infinite is certainly a positive number.

Answer (score 2):

I think Peter is right in this case. Area's that are non-zero, but infinite, are in the context where you are talking about, most of the time called "positive".

Comment: This question actually appeared in a national entrance exam. So there are no two ways about it.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to do a bit more research, and then I will make my answer better

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho The fact that a question appears on an exam (even a national entrance one) often has little to do with whether or not it is well phrased, fully specified or even correct in any sense of the word. To me it seems unlikely to be obvious whether the region you specify has positive area. In terms of lebesgue measure it's infinite and thus probably positive (lebesgue measure is always positive or 0). In general all areas are positive or 0, but there are some places where we talk about negative areas such as riemannian integration. There areas below the x-axis are negative.

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho The main problem with the question as phrased though in my opinion, is that it is fully dependent on the definition of a positive area and is one of those edge cases where definitions between mathematical disciplines or even different schools might differ. It's a bit like the question whether or not $0$ is a natural number. This depends on if you ask a set theorist or an algebraic number theorist.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not wrong at all. The area may be infinite, but positive infinite. So yes.

Comment: I guess it is not a standardized affair. What I was thinking is that positive area means the area is a positive number.

Comment: Yes, but if you are going to search for the definition of a "positive" area, you will find that most of the time an area is called positive if it's not negative.

Comment: So does positive area and non-zero area mean the same thing in this context?

Comment: Yeah, in this context it does. But I'm not saying that positive and non-zero are the same thing in general. Don't understand me wrong ;)